# Simple query: Northernmost city of each country? (latitude, city, country)

Tags: sql

I have to write a query to find the northernmost city in each country.  One of the tables contains "string nulls" which is why the not 'null' is included.

Here is a picture of the access query design:  [image: query layout]

I don't understand why this query isn't working.  Aren't I supposed to be grouping by both city and country, and then only show the highest latitude per each grouping?  But, if I do "group by" latitude instead of "max", I get the same results; it's listing all latitudes in the results.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I feel ridiculous asking such a simple question here but I'm not sure how to get this to work!

Comment: What do you mean by "string nulls"? If you have "null" stored as string, then you condition should be `<> 'null'` If it is a usual null, then the condition should be `not null`

Comment: The condition reverted to <> 'null' on its own after I re-opened the query.  String null was a bad way to phrase it, I meant its not a true null, but a value called 'NULL'.

By not working I mean the results are showing ALL latitudes that are not 'NULL' rather than just the highest latitudes grouped by city & country.  I figured using Max as the total would only show the Top 1 latitude per city & country combination, but I'm wrong.

Comment: Your query doesn't work because it is doing exactly that: "Top 1 latitude per city & country combination". While you want "find top latitude for each country and show the corresponding city for it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/max_query2.php
`col1` is your `CountryName` and `col3` is your `CityName`. Anc `col2` is the latitude.

The basic idea is to first find max latitude for each country and then join the result back to the original data to find the corresponding city names.

Comment: This was a bad question to ask.  I had just found this resource myself minutes before you pointed it to me, I didn't do enough research on my own before coming here.  This was unnecessary and lazy on my part.  Thank you for the help.  I'll avoid asking unnecessary questions in the future.